# Why is the voltage output from an arduino positive?

Tags: arduino

If I connect the common ground (COM) probe of my voltmeter to the positive side of a 9V battery and connect the voltage probe to the negative side, I read -9V (or thereabouts). This lines up well with my mental model of non-conventional current flow and how it's the negatively charged electron that's flowing from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive.

So why is it when I connect the COM probe to the GND pin on my Arduino and the voltage pin to the 5V pin, I get a +5V reading?

How does that work? Do I need to wire all of my circuits backwards when powered by an Arduino?

Comment: `So why is it when I connect the COM probe to the GND pin on my Arduino and the voltage pin to the 5V pin, I get a +5V reading?` You can connect the COM probe to the output pin, and the voltage probe to the ground (just as you did with the battery) and get -5v, would that solve the problem?

Comment: @alexan_e That wouldn't solve the problem. In a battery, the positive terminal is 0V, which is equivalent to ground, right? But it seems to be the opposite in the Arduino. Switching my probes wouldn't change that there seems to be a reverse polarity in the Arduino vs. a 9V battery.

Comment: @NickRamirez: Neither terminal of the battery is 0 volts until _you_ decide which terminal you will connect the common lead of the meter to.  If you put the black meter lead on the negative terminal, then the positive terminal will be +9 volts.

Comment: To continue with Peter Bennett's comment, you can decide to pick any node in a circuit and declare it to be ground...it isn't ground until you say it is. In digital circuits the lowest voltage point is usually chosen to be ground. In analog circuits the chosen ground point may be exactly half way between the highest and lowest voltages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ground", in most electronics, is simply the place in the ciruit that we choose to call "zero volts", and use as a reference when measuring voltage elsewhere in the circuit.  It is where we put the black (common) lead of our meter.

In most cases these days, "Ground" is the most negative terminal of the power supply, so all voltages elsewhere will be positive.  However, we do sometimes call the positive terminal of the power supply "Ground", then voltages elsewhere will be negative.

It is common in analog circuits to call the midpoint of the power supply "Ground", then we will have both positive and negative voltages.

When you put the common lead of your meter on the positive terminal of the 9 volt battery, you effectively declared the positive terminal as "Ground", so the meter says the negative terminal is -9 volts.  If you had instead put the black (common) meter lead on the negative terminal, you would have declared the negative terminal as ground, so the poistiver terminal would be +9 volts.

Comment: A very thorough answer. Just need to wrap my mind around it, since I've always considered the positive terminal of the battery to be 0V (no electrical potential).

Comment: Hopefully the other answers and comments have you thinking clearly about this. If not, think of your comment: "I've always considered the positive terminal of the battery to be 0V (no electrical potential)". Electrical potential is meaningless unless it defined in terms of the *relative potential between two specific points*.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yep, this has helped. I think from now on, before using voltage source, I'll get out my voltmeter to see its relation to GND (or what I'm using as GND anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

The 9v battery

[image]

has a positive pole and a negative pole, none of them is the ground.

Your multimeter has "COM" input and a "V" input, when you connect a voltage across them the display shows the voltage difference of the "V" input referenced to "COM".

When the voltage connected to "V" is negative in reference to the "COM" voltage then you get a negative reading (like with the battery).
When the voltage connected to "V" is positive in reference to the "COM" voltage then you get a positive reading (like with arduino).

Reversing the two leads of the multimeter will change the sign on the display but the voltage sources are still the same, it's a matter of what you select as your reference point.

Answer (score 0):

It works because by definition the 5V pin is 5 volts higher potential than the GND pin, so it's good that you're reading +5V. Another way to phrase that is that the GND pin in 5 volts lower potential than the 5V pin, thus if you measure from 5V to GND you'll read -5V.

Do not wire your circuits backwards and do not over think the what electron flow should mean in terms of voltage. Know whats going on, but use the model as it's defined.

Comment: Could you relate this to a 9V battery?

Comment: On the 9V battery, the + terminal is 9 volts higher than the - terminal. On the arduino, the + terminal is 5 volts higher than the - or GND terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a useful thing to remember is Kirchhoff's voltage law, which states that the sum of all voltage drops in a loop will be zero. It's also assumed that the potential at all points connected directly by a wire is the same.

If you consider the loop A-B-C as follows (RL represents all the circuitry after the regulator that runs from the +5V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmYYGP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage from A to B is -4V, the voltage from B to C is -5V and the voltage from C to A is +9V. Total is 0.

If we flip the voltmeter probes, the voltage from B to A is +4V, the voltage from C to B is +5V, and the voltage from A to C is -9V. Again, the total is 0.

Note that when someone says the voltage is, say, +5V, it is assumed that there is a reference, and usually that reference is called ground or common. So, with the circuit shown, node A is at +9V, node B is at +5V, and node C (connected to the ground symbol), of course is at 0V.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a differential between arbitrary point A and arbitrary point B. What you consider Ground is simply the convention of "0v". You can measure a 9v battery or a 5v power supply as positive or negative, depending on which side you connect to your multimeter. In fact, a 9v battery can and often is used to provide -9v for audio devices that need both 9v and -9v, simply by connecting two 9v batteries in series, and using the mid point as the "Ground". And just as often, everybody is also used to this, by putting batteries in series for a higher voltage. Two 9v's represent -9V to +9V or 0V to +18V.

Comment: That makes logical sense. I've been setting up my circuits as the positive terminal being ground (since that's how electrical current flows, negative to positive). It's a reorientation to get the hang of a microcontroller that does it opposite!

Comment: @NickRamirez Actually that's wrong. Current flows from positive to negative, electrical current is *positive* charge flow. You're correct to say the electrons flow from negative to positive, but not current.

Comment: @Samuel, you're describing "conventional current". But in the physical world, current is defined as the number of electrons flowing past a point during one second -- an amp is one coulomb per second. Electrical current always flows negative to positive. That's the essence of why I was confused by a negative terminal being labeled GND.

Comment: @NickRamirez I can't imagine what you think you mean when you say it's defined in the 'physical world' in that way. Your definition of an amp is correct, except that you incorrectly assume a coulomb to be be made of electrons. A coulomb is *charge*, for [electrical and electronics engineering that charge is positive](http://xkcd.com/567/) and electrical current flows from positive to negative. It does not *always* flow from negative to positive, only if it's defined that way, and that isn't the case here.

Comment: @Samuel When I say the physical world, I mean how current actually works in the real world. It flows negative to positive. Conventional current follows the "holes" that are left behind by a moving electron. It's only in schematics and theory that there's conventional current. In the physical world, it's absolutely always a negatively charged electron that's moving.

Comment: @NickRamirez I know very well [how it works](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/85206/15805). The only aspect of your assertion that I can agree with is that the electron is the charge carrier and is moving. You still seem to think current=electrons, abandon that misconception. They are related but not the same, the thing we call current is moving in the opposite direction. You're welcome to redefine it for yourself or complain that it just isn't so, but it only leads to the confusion that brought you here in the first place.

Comment: @Samuel, I'll just reference a few 3rd party sources here of what electrical current is: http://physics.about.com/od/glossary/g/Current.htm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current, http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/electric%20current. All describe electrical current as the movement of electrons.  To be fair, electronic current is different from conventional current, which you are describing. My misconception that led to this question had to do with voltage and how it relates to ground.

Comment: @NickRamirez I see, your confusion is that you see "electric charge" and think it means "electron". Please re-read your own sources, they speak of the movement of electric charge, not electrons per se. It seems clear you didn't even read the Wikipedia page, take note of this sentence: "Because the electrons carry negative charge, their motion in a metal conductor is in the direction opposite to that of conventional (or *electric*) current." Emphasis is theirs.

Comment: @Samuel I'll say you've gotten me to really think about it. And I've learned more about it. An interesting article is here: http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html#frkel that suggest that we're both right. Current is the movement of electrical charge carriers. In metals, that charge carrier is the electron. But in other materials, that's not always the case. Very interesting!

Comment: @NickRamirez it's all irrelevant though, because the concept of "Ground" and ground terminals (or positive/negative) on batteries, come from the same thinking that created "conventional current" as you have mentioned. Initial and longstanding belief in how electricity and electrical circuits work will not easily be trumped by what is purely semantic and pedantic "technical rightness". All our tools (meters, diodes, schematics and symbols) are designed with the idea of positive to negative flow.